# Weird python3 string behavior

Tags: python-3.x, string

Here's the code to convert 12 hour time format to 24 hour format. Everything works fine except the 12 hour time AM (1:00:00 to 11:59:59) is acting weird and only returning 0.

Code :

```
def timeConversion(s):
    times = s.split(":")
    hour = int(times[0])
    minutes = times[1]
    seconds = times[2][:-2]
    timemod = times[-1][2:]

    military_hour=0


    if timemod=="AM" : 

        if hour == 12 : 

            miltary_hour = 0
        else:
            miltary_hour = hour

    elif timemod == "PM" : 

        if hour == 12 : 
            military_hour = hour
        else:
            military_hour = hour + 12



    if military_hour < 10 : 
        military_hour = "0" + str(military_hour)
    else:
        military_hour = str(military_hour)


    return ":".join([military_hour,minutes,seconds])

## below 2 are incorrect 
print(timeConversion("9:30:10AM"))
print(timeConversion("6:00:00AM"))

## these are correct 
print(timeConversion("12:00:00AM"))
print(timeConversion("12:00:00PM"))
print(timeConversion("11:59:59PM"))
```

The solution is

```
00:30:10                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
00:00:00                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
00:00:00                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
12:00:00                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
23:59:59
```

Why the heck AM time before noon always returns 00 instead of actual hour ?

Comment: your if else block is identical in AM case?

Comment: I had typo. I have edited the code which still has the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misspelled `military_hour` in the `AM` logic.

Here:

```
if timemod=="AM" : 
    if hour == 12 : 
        miltary_hour = 0
    else:
        miltary_hour = hour
```

Comment: you are the best. Me being sleepy can't think clearly. That was indeed that "silly" mistake in the code. I see correct results after fixing variable name.

Comment: @Prithi. I recommend deleting the question. This is too specific to be of much use to anyone else

Comment: @paradoxlover. I think so, assuming OP can delete with your answer present. But you'll get it back quickly it seems.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Right... The community comes first. And yes, I will get it back ;).

Comment: can't delete. Stack Overflow doesn't let me. I guess have to stick around with this one.

Comment: @paradoxlover. OP can only delete if you do :) I would just keep it around in your place, but I'm very selfish.

Answer (score -1):

**you can try this:**

```
time_12 = input().strip()
time_in_pm = time_12[-2:].lower() == 'pm'
time_list = list(map(int, time_12[:-2].split(':')))
if not time_in_pm and time_list[0] == 12:
    time_list[0] = 0
if time_in_pm and time_list[0] < 12:
    time_list[0] += 12
print(':'.join(map(lambda x: str(x).rjust(2, '0'), time_list)))
```

or You can also use the python date time library.